# Removing last two Zeros [AutoNumeric.js, JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `autonumeric.js` to generate currency number format, the problem is autonumeric's generating 2 more zeros after comma. e.g **40560000** became **40.560.000,00**

I want to remove the last 2 zeros, so instead of **40.560.000,00** the result of autonumeric will be **40.560.000**

This is my script :

```js
$('td.sub_total').autoNumeric('init', {aSep: '.', aDec: ','});
$('td.vat').autoNumeric('init', {aSep: '.', aDec: ','});
$('td.total').autoNumeric('init', {aSep: '.', aDec: ','});
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://decorplanit.com/plugin/), you can simply use the `mDec` key in the object.

Example:

```
$('td.sub_total').autoNumeric('init', {aSep: '.', aDec: ',', mDec: '0'});
$('td.vat').autoNumeric('init', {aSep: '.', aDec: ',', mDec: '0'});
$('td.total').autoNumeric('init', {aSep: '.', aDec: ',', mDec: '0'});
```

Comment: Well, I didn't read the documentation you mentioned above, thanks, it works :D

Comment: `mDec` is the decimal place override. Using `vMin`/`vMax` is the primary way to set the number of decimals you want. In your case you should just use integers in those two options, and no decimals will appear.

Comment: With AutoNumeric `v4` onward, `decimalPlaceOverride` has been dropped in favor of a more explicit way to specify the number of decimal places : `decimalPlaces`. That's it ;)

Comment: See mDec, vMin, vMax, and aPad from: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/  You can also attribute you're elements with those data attributes rather than having to defined different autoNumerics.  For example a min and a max with up to 4 decimal precision points and to not pad with 0s: <input type="text" class="form-control" data-v-min="-9999999999999.9999" data-v-max="9999999999999.9999" data-a-pad="false">

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in a comment by Alex:

for autoNumeric v4+ the proper way to do this is to use:

```
{decimalPlaces:'0'}
```

Answer (score 2):

autonumeric.js provide option (aPad) to remove unneccessary zero numbers. You can try this flow the source code above.
You can try:

```
    // wacth change opts and re-instance autoNumeric
    scope.$watch(() => {
        return $(element).attr('kv-auto-numeric'); // set a watch on the actual DOM value
    },
    (val: string) => {
        opts = angular.extend({}, this.options, scope.$eval(val)) as AutoNumericOptions;

        // remove unneccessary zero numbers
        opts.aPad = false;
        element.autoNumeric('update', opts);
    });
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: autonumeric.js provide option (aPad) to remove unneccessary zero numbers.

You can try this flow the source code above.

Comment: Please add all explanation to the answer itself, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0):

Autonumeric contains an option called "allowDecimalPadding". If this option is set as true, padding is only done when there are some decimals.

[Autonumeric npm.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autonumeric)